# Do I need parallel/sticky states?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

When the page is first navigated to I want the map view to be visible with nothing in the detail view. When something is selected from a drop down I want the state to change and it's view be visible in the detail view while the map view remains visible.

Occasionally (and herein lies the problem), I want to be able to click on a link in the details view that navigates to a state where the details view remains visible but the map view switches to the data view.

Is this possible with default `ui-router api` or do i need `sticky/parallel` states?

**EDIT: YES IT IS POSSIBLE WITHOUT STICKYSTATES**

This is the layout:

## UPDATED:

```
               default layout
-----------------------------------------
|       [dropdown][dropdown][dropdown]  
|------- --------------------------------
| [details |
|   view]  |          [viewport view]
|          |              
|          |          
|          |                                
------------------------------------------
```

1. User navigates to page:
   Basically a `default state` where the only visible view is the `viewport view` with a `MAP template`.
2. User selects a drop down option from the `default state` / layout.
   State should transition to a `default.detailX state` (there will be several different detail states). In each of these `default.detailX states` the `details view` should now be visible with the corresponding `detailX template`.  The `viewport view` should remain visible with the `MAP template` displayed.

**HERE IS WHERE I BEGIN TO HAVE PROBLEMS, and based on the desired behavior and advice from the comments, I think what should happen here is:**

3. User clicks link in `default.detailX`, and app should transition to a `default.detailX.data state` where the viewport switches from the `MAP template` to the `DATA template`

Is this the correct way of doing this? Yes.

## Updated again with solution (thanks shershen for the direction):

```
$stateProvider
            .state('default', {
                url: '/mpkapp',
                views: {
                    '': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/layout.html'
                    },
                    'viewport@default': { template: '<state-map />' }
                }
            })
            .state('default.districtdetails', {
                url: '/districts/:districtid/details',
                params: { districtid: null },
                views: {
                    'detail': { template: '<div district-details-view></div>' }
                }
            })
            .state('default.districtdetails.data', {
                url: '/districts/:districtid/usage?=:districtname&=:mfgid&=:manufacturername',
                views: {
                    'detail': { template: '<div district-details-view></div>' },
                    'viewport@default': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/product.usage.html',
                        controller: 'ProductUsageController'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('default.districts', {
                url: '/county/:fips?=:county',
                params: { fips: null, county: null },
                views:
                {
                    'detail': { template: '<div county-district-list></div>' }
                }
            })
            .state('default.distributordistricts', {
                params: { distributorid: null, distributorname: null },
                url: '/distributors/:distributorid/districts?=:distributorname',
                views:
                {
                    'detail': {
                        template: '<div distributor-district-list></div>'
                    }
                }
            })
```

Doing this I am able to change the `viewport view` from a child state of `default` while it remains the same in it's sibling states.

Comment: If you mean that you want to show dropdowns always, no mater what view/state is that - you just wrap them in additional view section that will be present in all state

Comment: No, I want to show drop downs always... they are already wrapped in their own view section. No problems there.  The problem is: I want to be able to select an option from a drop down which will navigate to one of many detail states/views and have a map view/state that remains visible. Once in a while I want to be able to click on a link from a detail view and switch from the map view to the data view while the detail view remains visible.

Comment: So in short - you want to toggle Map / Data displaying only in default.detailX state ?

Comment: Haha, yes.  I've been up on an all-nighter, I apologize for the total lack of clarity.  However your example below gave me the insight I needed to solve the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: NP! You can achieve that by crating for example default.detailX.map and default.detailX.detail substates of the default.detailX state. Referring to sample cod in my answer - where in default.detailX.map - view named 'centralblock' shows MAP and in default.detailX.detail state view named 'centralblock' shows DETAIL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all possible with combination of states with views. Some states may have the same views shown, others show different templates in the same place. More on that here: [Multiple Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views). It can be smth like this:

in template

```
<ui-view name="dropdown"></ui-view> //top
<ui-view name="detail"></ui-view> //left
<ui-view name="centralblock"></ui-view> //main area
```

in states config

```
$stateProvider.state('state', {
 views: {
      'dropdown': { //always shown, add templates and/or controllers },
      'detail': {},
      'centralblock': { //show map template here },
    }
}).state('state2', {
 views: {
      'dropdown': { //always shown, add templates and/or controllers },
      'detail': {},
      'centralblock': {//show data template here},
    }
})
```

Comment: So actually then, would I want to do something like above, but with say a default state showing the dropdowns and an empty detail template, and the map template in centralblock. Then when the user selects an item from the dropdown navigate to a  'default.detail1' state with a detail view and a centralblock view showing the map template, then  when the user clicks a link in the detail view, it would navigate to a 'default.detail1.data' state that had a detail view the same as the default.detail1 state and a centralblock view with the data template instead of the map template? sorry confusing.

Comment: sorry, really confusing to understand. maybe drawing diagrams like here http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state would help?